# AngularJs controller data not visible in html directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've made a login directive that looks like this:

**directive login**

```
  (function() {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('lnjapp.login',[])
            .directive('login', login);

        function login() {
            var directive = {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/login/login.html',
                restrict: 'E',
                Controller: login.controller,
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            };
            return directive;
        }   
    })();
```

**login.controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('lnjapp.login')
        .controller('loginController', loginController);

    function loginController()
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.test = 'test';
    }
})();
```

**login.html**

```
        <div class="form-group pull-left">
            <label>
                <b>d{{ vm.test }}</b>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Onhoud mij
            </label>
            <br>
            <a ng-href="#/wachtwoord/vergeten">Wachtwoord Vergeten?</a>
        </div>
```

In `login.html` `vm.test` is empty?

What could be wrong here?

Comment: swap login.controller for 'loginController'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:
1. Controller name is incorrect in the directive
2. Controller name should be in single quotes

Try below code:

```
(function() {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('lnjapp.login',[])
            .directive('login', login)
            .controller('loginController', loginController);

            function loginController()
            {
              var vm = this;
              vm.test = 'test';
            };

        function login() {
            var directive = {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/login/login.html',
                restrict: 'E',
                controller: 'loginController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            };
            return directive;
        }   
    })();
```

Comment: Thankyou that's working. But when I put the controller in a separated file it's not? The controller is linked in my index.html

Comment: Yes this can be happened and the reason is, when you create controller is a separate file since you are creating 'lnjapp.login' module in a separate file so there may be the case that 'lnjapp.login' module is not available and we are creating controller over it.                                                                   So if you have decided to put controllers and services in the different file then you will have to make sure the before adding controllers/services over it, module is created and ready to use.

Comment: Is it a bad practice to put it in the same file?

Comment: yes if you have too many modules in your project then you should not be using single file. You can use RequireJS/CoomonJS to modularize your application and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

in the directive in should be a variable name not a file name

```
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('lnjapp.login',[])
        .directive('login', login);
    function loginController()
    {
       var vm = this;
       vm.test = 'test';
    }
    function login() {
        var directive = {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/login/login.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            Controller: loginController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };
        return directive;
    }   
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access controller data from the view, you should bind it to the scope. So in your case you should user `$scope.vm = "test";` and in the view only use `{{vm}}` that should do the trick as far as I can see.

For further information about AngularJS's two way data binding see: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04